# How can I handle application cleanup on Phusion Passenger restarts?

Tags: passenger

I use Phusion Passenger + Apache to run various applications. At deployment time we take advantage of it's file based restart by touching `<<app_dir>>/tmp/restart.txt`.

One thing has always eluded me... what does Passenger do to the old process? I've been troubleshooting some cleanup tasks in one of our applications that don't seem to run when passenger stops the process.

The application traps `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` signals so I'm guessing that Passenger isn't using either of them. Does anyone know for certain what passenger does to processes at restart or have experience with the same issue (application cleanup at Passenger restart)?

Any information, ideas, or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tim Birkett.